# Which context to use in DialogFragment when showing ReyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

Hopefully it's a quick answer where I feel a little like a dummy, but I'm trying to show a RecyclerView control in a DialogFragment. Here's the important stuff of what I have so far...

```
public class FooBarFragment extends DialogFragment {
...
...
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foobar, container, false);
    List<Foobar> foobars = DataManager.getInstance().getFoobars();

    RecyclerView recyclerFoobars = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.foobar_recycler_buttons);
    recyclerFoobars.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), 3));
    recyclerFoobars.setAdapter(new FoobarRecyclerAdapter(this.getContext(), foobars));
}
```

I've been able to get this particular RecyclerView to display on a stand-alone activity, but when I try to show it in a DialogFragment, I get nothing. Note - the dialog actually displays, there are some other controls that show up, but not the RecyclerView.

I ***think*** the problem has to do with the context I'm passing, but I've tried this way and I've tried passing `requireActivity()` to get the calling activity's context, but neither worked. It's my understanding that I should be passing the `Fragment`'s context, but I could be mistaken on that.

EDIT: My `fragment_foobar`'s RecyclerView and RecyclerAdapter are below...

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/room_recycler_buttons"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/some_control"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/some_other_control"
 tools:listitem="@layout/item_gridview" />
```

```
public class FoobarRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoobarRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<Foobar> mFoobars;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public FoobarRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Foobar> foobarList) {
        mContext = context;
        mFoobars = foobarList;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gridview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Foobar foobar = mFoobars.get(position);
        holder.mFoobarButton.setText(foobar.getFoobarName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFoobars.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final Button mFoobarButton;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mFoobarButton= (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_gridview_button);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show `R.layout.fragment_foobar` ?

Comment: Sure! I'll update the question, too long for comments.

Comment: please edit your question, and add it also add the `FoobarRecyclerAdapter`

Comment: Um... maybe the wrong question! Just tried playing with the margins and it IS displaying, but the 0dp width and height was just making it unable to be seen! I thought setting the height and width to 0dp was just matching the constraint though? In the design view that's what it does at least.

Comment: Another question for another thread, but this ended up being a problem with the width and height of the `ReyclerView` control. I thought that `0dp` meant match constraint (and it does), but when dealing with a `DialogFragment` there seems to be something more complex there (maybe on account of the `DialogFragment` not being created at first?). Either way, thanks @Zain for telling me to post the fragment's XML, would have never thought the problem was in there!

Answer (score 0):

Going off Zain's recommendation to post my `RecyclerView` control's XML, got me thinking about the width and height. `0dp` means `match_constraint` but when doing it in a DialogFragment, there appears to be some more nuance. That's another question for another thread though.

Changing the `width` and `height` to appropriate values got the `RecyclerView` control to display in my `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Probably it has to do with the parent. That is, in an activity, the content view is full screen, so a recyclerview with MATCH_CONSTRAINTS will stretch to fill... but in a dialog the content view is wrapping the contents, so there's nothing to give the recycler any height.